# Opencv authentication

Tags: opencv, authentication, face-recognition

Is it possible to use opencv to authenticate users by their face?

I mean not identification, but authentication, when user enters his name and face is used instead of password. So, I should not get the label of the given face, cause it is known (username), but the distance of the input image (face) and the face in training set with given label.
There will be base of some thousands users.

Comment: sure it's possible, just don't underestimate the work required to make it happen. grabbing some classification code (e.g. from opencv) is the easy part, hardening that for a large user base a total different story.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three methods for face recognition on OpenCV:

- Eigenfaces
- Fisherfaces
- Local Binary Patterns Histograms

I've already made a proof of concept for Eigenfaces and it is pretty accurate (not a lot of tests were made).

This tutorial might help you:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

You will need to also extra work to create a database to store face information to use it as credentials of a system. 
I'm also not sure how reliable it would be (let say there are twin brothers, will it differentiate them? If someone ages, it will still be fine?), but it might be useful for most of the systems (if extra security is needed, add also another kind of validation to be sure - face and fingerprint, for instance).